# Metatags con o sin acento

Tags: html, html5

¿Los `metatags` deben ponerse con o sin acento?

Es decir, así:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="camión, árbol, lápiz"/>
```

¿O así?

```
<meta name="keywords" content="camion, arbol, lapiz"/>
```

**Mi duda realmente es** si los indexadores pueden reconocer los acentos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mi duda realmente es sí los indexadores pueden reconocer los acentos.

**SI**, los *buscadores* pueden reconocer los acentos de tus `metatags` sin embargo esto afectará de manera directa los resultados de búsqueda en los mismos, simplemente te aconsejaría añadir la codificación que ocupes, por ejemplo:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

[Aquí](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=avion&oq=avion&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.534j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) puedes ver una búsqueda en google y comparar la diferencia de resultados con [esta](https://www.google.com.co/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=avi%C3%B3n) otra respecto a la palabra ***Avion*** y ***Avión***, respectivamente.

Como puedes observar la primera búsqueda con la palabra ***Avion*** nos arrojó:

> Cerca de 100,000,000 resultados (0.63 segundos)

Y con ***Avión***:

> Cerca de 56,800,000 resultados (0.66 segundos)

[Aquí](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=massotherapie+montreal&oq=massotherapie+montreal&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4878j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) tienes otro ejemplo con dos palabras más sin tildes, y las [mismas](https://www.google.com.co/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=massoth%C3%A9rapie%20montr%C3%A9al) con tilde; ***massotherapie montreal***, ***massothérapie montréal***.

En conclusión **puedes ponerlos con tilde** sin embargo de un modo u otro la búsqueda se verá directamente afectada a través de los navegadores.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que no habria problema , aunque haciendo un poco de busqueda la especificacion  del charset no tiene nada que ver con la codificacion de las `metas`.

charset: Especifica la codificación de caracteres para el documento HTML

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

entonces llegamos a concluir que el `UTF-8` solo codificara al contenido del html y no así a los meta.
pero dando una alternativa a tu problema, puedes tener varios

```
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript">
  <meta name="author" content="John Doe">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

**con eso tu puedes poner un meta con acento y otro sin acento**

Comment: las metas son para dar informaciones sobre la página... la codificación no aplica a las demás metas...

Comment: @aldanux No afecta directamente las demás metas pero si afecta la búsqueda y mucho más si, como en este caso, tiene metas con acentos.